# How to add css files to Spring boot application (Thymeleaf) pagination

Tags: java, spring-boot, pagination, thymeleaf

I try to make pagination in my web site.

my PostController.java file contains:

```
@GetMapping("/")
    public String index(Model model) {
        return findPaginated(0, model);
    }


@GetMapping("/page/{pageNo}")
    public String findPaginated(
            @PathVariable("pageNo") int pageNo,
            Model model
    ) {
        int pageSize = 3;

        Page<Post> page = postService.findPaginated(pageNo, pageSize);
        List<Post> listPosts = page.getContent();

        model.addAttribute("currentPage", pageNo);
        model.addAttribute("totalPages", page.getTotalPages());
        model.addAttribute("totalItems", page.getTotalElements());

        model.addAttribute("page", page);

        int totalPages = page.getTotalPages();

        if (totalPages > 0) {
            List<Integer> pageNumbers = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, totalPages).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
            model.addAttribute("pageNumbers", pageNumbers);
        }

        model.addAttribute("listPosts", listPosts);

         return "index";
    }
```

and index.html file contains:

```
<head xmlna:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
--snip--
<link href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
--snip--

</head>

<body>

--snip--

 <!-- ADDING PAGINATION-->

                <nav aria-label="...">
                    <ul class="pagination">
                        <li class="page-item">
                            <a class="page-link"
                               th:href="@{'/page/' + ${currentPage - 1}}"
                               th:if="${currentPage < totalPages + 1 and currentPage > 1}">Previous</a>
                        </li>
                        <li th:class="${pageNumber == page.getNumber() + 1} ? 'page-item active': 'page-item'"
                            th:each="pageNumber: ${pageNumbers}" th:if="${page.getTotalPages() > 0}">
                            <a class="page-link"
                               th:href="@{'/page/' + ${pageNumber}}"
                               th:text="${pageNumber}">
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="page-item">
                            <a class="page-link"
                               th:href="@{'/page/' + ${currentPage + 1}}"
                               th:if="${currentPage < totalPages and currentPage >= 1}">Next</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

                <!-- /ADDING PAGINATION-->

--snip--

</body>
```

When program runs for the first time everything looks right. So I add some posts (this app is about writing posts and showing them in index.html file) and when I want to go for example:
`localhost:8080/page/1` **css, js and img** files didn't upload. I inspected and checked network, and it shows me `localhost:8080/page/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css`  didn't upload.Actually, it must be `localhost:8080/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css` . But why exactly this path it shows me?

How could I fix it?

If you didn't get question, then I uploaded some extra images for better understanding:

[image: Here is folders containing html and css]

[image: This is my html file with thymeleaf]

[image: When program starts and add some posts we can see this part]

[image: If I click for example 2 then css, js and img files didn't upload]

[image: here is the link]

[image: This is what we can see when inspecting localhost:8080/page/2]

Thanks in advance. I hope you get it.

Comment: try to add additional slash at start here before assets <link href="/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: Thank you very much, you know I searched about this question several days and finally (thanks to you) solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add additional **/** at start here before assets

```
<link href="/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had such a problem recently. I was sure I had no problem like "/". Later, I saw that the use of `<link href="/exampleDirectory/style.css" rel="stylesheet">` was arranged differently for Thymeleaf.

If anyone has a problem like me, try using `<link th:href="@{/example/table.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>`.

You can find an example [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-thymeleaf-css-js).

EDIT:

I guess what's done here is to use expressions in a way that Thymeleaf can parse. We already know that we need to specify a CSS file with `href` to be able to use it in HTML files. However, as far as I understand, if we are going to use Thymeleaf on the Spring side, we need to give some things in a way that it can parse.

Here is a statement from the Thymeleaf docs:

> The Thymeleaf standard dialects –called Standard and SpringStandard– offer a way to easily create URLs in your web applications so that they include any required URL preparation artifacts. This is done by means of the so-called link expressions, a type of Thymeleaf Standard Expression: @{...}.

In this way, when we fill in `th:href`, Thymeleaf will resolve it for us. At least that's what I understand.

For details and more, please check: [Standard URL Syntax](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html#:%7E:text=Server%2Drelative%20URLs,%2FshowDetails.htm%7D%22%3E)

Comment: You mean, the first statement is different than the second one?

Comment: I edited the actual comment since it is a bit long explanation. Please check it out.